# What is causing these errors in my Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting the following errors when a Heroku worker runs a delayed_job and cannot work out why. The first error seems related to the [Evernote gem](https://github.com/cgs/evernote), even though I don't actually have any code at all which uses it yet in the entire project. All I have is

```
gem 'evernote', "~> 0.9.0"
```

in the gemfile.

The second one seems related to the [Newrelic](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic) Heroku addon, which is an application monitoring service. But it does monitor the application so I have no idea what could be causing the error.

What is causing these errors?

1st

```
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 heroku[worker.3]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: rake aborted!
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: SIGTERM
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/evernote-0.9.0/vendor/gen-rb/evernote.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-11T03:31:22+00:00 heroku[worker.3]: Process exited
2011-05-10T20:31:23-07:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from up to stopping
```

2nd

```
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: rake aborted!
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: SIGTERM
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:38:in `extend'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:38:in `<module:Pages>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:37:in `<module:Caching>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:6:in `<module:ActionController>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:60:in `<module:Caching>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:31:in `<module:ActionController>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:192:in `<class:Base>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:167:in `<module:ActionController>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/control/frameworks/rails.rb:127:in `install_shim'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/control.rb:137:in `init_plugin'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/vendor/plugins/rpm/init.rb:26:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81:in `eval'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 app[worker.2]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
2011-05-11T03:31:25+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Process exited
```

EDIT:

Here is the stack info:

```
Stack: bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

EDIT 2:

Here is another one:

```
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.1]: "success - end"
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:9c66d1f3-82a1-4489-b20b-b8460a467223 pid:1)] Mixpanel completed after 1.7464
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:9c66d1f3-82a1-4489-b20b-b8460a467223 pid:1)] 2 jobs processed at 0.1720 j/s, 0 failed ...
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.3]: rake aborted!
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.3]: SIGTERM
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/blankslate.rb:107:in `append_features'
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:35:in `include'
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 app[worker.3]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2011-05-19T02:07:07+00:00 heroku[worker.3]: Process exited
2011-05-18T19:07:08-07:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-19T02:07:08+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:df710df0-7b32-42b7-b477-b810485b5dc7 pid:1)] RPM Monitoring DJ worker host:df710df0-7b32-42b7-b477-b810485b5dc7 pid:1
2011-05-19T02:07:08+00:00 app[worker.2]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2011-05-19T02:07:08+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:df710df0-7b32-42b7-b477-b810485b5dc7 pid:1)] Starting job worker
2011-05-19T02:07:09+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-19T02:07:09+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:df710df0-7b32-42b7-b477-b810485b5dc7 pid:1)] Exiting...
2011-05-19T02:07:11+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Starting process with command: `rake jobs:work`
2011-05-19T02:07:14+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Process exited
2011-05-19T02:07:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:5d665233-0dc4-4151-aab2-a64b7656df07 pid:1)] RPM Monitoring DJ worker host:5d665233-0dc4-4151-aab2-a64b7656df07 pid:1
2011-05-19T02:07:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2011-05-19T02:07:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:5d665233-0dc4-4151-aab2-a64b7656df07 pid:1)] Starting job worker
```

Comment: what heroku stack? if you don't use the evernote gem, get rid of it! What cache have you set up? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I have added the stack information to the question. Haven't done any cache setup, so I'm not sure about that? Regarding the evernote gem, I am going to be using soon so I'd like to work out how I can have it in my gemfile without causing errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: does it work without the gem or not?

Answer (score 3):

The only time I've ever got the message "Stopping process with SIGTERM" has been when I have terminated the process manually - eg when I was running script/server and then hit CTRL-C

This is an operating system message saying that the process was terminated by somebody on purpose. It is not an internal failure.

I suggest you have a chat with the heroku people about whether your process was doing something silly and they terminated it.

Comment: Hey @ben Just noticed - this answer isn't accepted (though you did award the bounty)...  :)

Answer (score 2):

from heroku help:

R12 - Exit timeout

A process failed to exit within 10 seconds of being sent a SIGTERM indicating that it should stop. The process is sent SIGKILL to force an exit.

See:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r12__exit_timeout

Seems you need more quickly code.